# why some properties in office-js typings are mandatory

Tags: typescript, office-js

Curious why some of these properties in the office-js typings are mandatory. For example in

```
export interface AsyncResult {
    asyncContext: any;
    status: AsyncResultStatus;
    error: Error;
    value: any;
}
```

If the AsyncResultStatus was Succeeded, its probably perfectly valid to not have to set any Error. Would appreciate any thoughts/feedback on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Shared API" portion of the office-js typings (anything under the `Office` namespace, as opposed to `Excel` or `Word` for the 2016 APIs) is something that was manually hand-crafted some time ago.  I say "manually", in the sense that the APIs under `Excel`, `Word`, etc namespaces have all been machine-generated.  So for these manual portions, there may be some minor discrepancies.

That being said, for your particular case, I actually don't see the problem.  You would never be *creating* an `AsyncResult` object, you would only be receiving one.  And so while it's true that realistically only a portion of that object will be filled in, I also see no issue with the way it's currently defined.  What is the case where it's preventing you from doing something that you'd like to do?

Comment: attempting to implement some of these functions that return AsyncResult.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand.  Wouldn't you just be consuming those functions?  At any rate, feel free to send a pull request on the definitelytyped project for office-JS